How to create bootable Debian SD Card for an Allwinner SBC using a USB SD Card adapter?
I got Raspbian running on an old Raspberry Pi 2B to install Debian for the Olimex Lime 2.
However, I read this warning on the Debian Wiki[1]:

These images are meant for the SD card slot on the device and will not work when SD card is inserted into USB based SD card readers. Once the installer is started, it runs completely in the system's RAM and does not need to load anything from the SD card anymore, so you can delete all existing partitions and use the full card for installing Debian. It is recommended to use the "guided partitioning" option in the installer to create a proper partition layout on the SD card.

I do not think that any of my devices have have built-in readers for SD cards except the Olimex itself. How can I create a bootable SD card for the Lime 2 using a USB adapter?
Is it possible to do so? Or must I utilize a laptop with a built in SD card reader to make the image?

Is Debian just saying that the Olimex Lime 2 cannot boot from a USB SD card adapter with this image? Or that I cannot make a bootable image using an SD Card adapter?

Not quite a solution, but unofficial(?) Debian images for the platform are released by Olimex: http://images.olimex.com/release/a20/

The images can be written to SD cards using any SD reader. The warning only applies to booting the cards on Olimex devices: for that purpose, only the built-in SD card reader can be used.
